# How to render SkyBox correctly?

Tags: java, libgdx

I used the solution to this question to draw a 3D SKybox view using 6 images .The question is found here .
[LibGDX 0.9.9 - Apply cubemap in environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884805/libgdx-0-9-9-apply-cubemap-in-environment). The program works but it seems to use a lot of processing power and my cpu fan starts to run. Is there a problem with the way i am rendering the 3D skybox or is there a better way to do it. Is the way I am implementing the skybox correct. Here is my code.

The Class to create the environment is below

```
protected final Pixmap[] data = new Pixmap[6];  
protected ShaderProgram shader;

protected int u_worldTrans;
protected Mesh quad;
private Matrix4 worldTrans;
private Quaternion q;

protected String vertexShader = " attribute vec3 a_position; \n"+
        " attribute vec3 a_normal; \n"+
        " attribute vec2 a_texCoord0; \n"+          
        " uniform mat4 u_worldTrans; \n"+                   
        " varying vec2 v_texCoord0; \n"+
        " varying vec3 v_cubeMapUV; \n"+            
        " void main() { \n"+
        "     v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;     \n"+
        "     vec4 g_position = u_worldTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0); \n"+
        "     v_cubeMapUV = normalize(g_position.xyz); \n"+
        "     gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0); \n"+
        " } \n";

protected String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES \n"+
        " precision mediump float; \n"+
        " #endif \n"+           
        " uniform samplerCube u_environmentCubemap; \n"+            
        " varying vec2 v_texCoord0; \n"+
        " varying vec3 v_cubeMapUV; \n"+            
        " void main() {      \n"+
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(textureCube(u_environmentCubemap, v_cubeMapUV).rgb, 1.0);   \n"+
        " } \n";

public String getDefaultVertexShader(){
    return vertexShader;
}

public String getDefaultFragmentShader(){
    return fragmentShader;
}

public EnvironmentCubemap (Pixmap positiveX, Pixmap negativeX, Pixmap positiveY, Pixmap negativeY, Pixmap positiveZ, Pixmap negativeZ) {
    data[0]=positiveX;
    data[1]=negativeX;

    data[2]=positiveY;
    data[3]=negativeY;

    data[4]=positiveZ;
    data[5]=negativeZ;

    init();   
}

public EnvironmentCubemap (FileHandle positiveX, FileHandle negativeX, FileHandle positiveY, FileHandle negativeY, FileHandle positiveZ, FileHandle negativeZ) {
    this(new Pixmap(positiveX), new Pixmap(negativeX), new Pixmap(positiveY), new Pixmap(negativeY), new Pixmap(positiveZ), new Pixmap(negativeZ));
}

//IF ALL SIX SIDES ARE REPRESENTED IN ONE IMAGE
public EnvironmentCubemap (Pixmap cubemap) {        
    int w = cubemap.getWidth();
    int h = cubemap.getHeight();
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) data[i] = new Pixmap(w/4, h/3, Format.RGB888);
    for(int x=0; x<w; x++)
        for(int y=0; y<h; y++){
            //-X
            if(x>=0 && x<=w/4 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[1].drawPixel(x, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            //+Y
            if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=0 && y<=h/3) data[2].drawPixel(x-w/4, y, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            //+Z
            if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[4].drawPixel(x-w/4, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            //-Y
            if(x>=w/4 && x<=w/2 && y>=h*2/3 && y<=h) data[3].drawPixel(x-w/4, y-h*2/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            //+X
            if(x>=w/2 && x<=w*3/4 && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[0].drawPixel(x-w/2, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
            //-Z
            if(x>=w*3/4 && x<=w && y>=h/3 && y<=h*2/3) data[5].drawPixel(x-w*3/4, y-h/3, cubemap.getPixel(x, y));
        }
    cubemap.dispose();
    cubemap=null;
    init();     
}

private void init(){        
     shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
        if (!shader.isCompiled())
            throw new GdxRuntimeException(shader.getLog());

     u_worldTrans = shader.getUniformLocation("u_worldTrans");

     quad = createQuad();      
     worldTrans = new Matrix4();         
     q = new Quaternion();

     initCubemap();
} 

private void initCubemap(){
    //bind cubemap
    Gdx.gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[0].getWidth(), data[0].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[0].getPixels());
    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[1].getWidth(), data[1].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[1].getPixels());

    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[2].getWidth(), data[2].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[2].getPixels());
    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[3].getWidth(), data[3].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[3].getPixels());

    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[4].getWidth(), data[4].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[4].getPixels());
    Gdx.gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, 0, GL30.GL_RGB, data[5].getWidth(), data[5].getHeight(), 0, GL30.GL_RGB, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[5].getPixels());

    Gdx.gl.glGenerateMipmap(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
    Gdx.gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL30.GL_LINEAR);

    Gdx.gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL30.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );     
    Gdx.gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL30.GL_LINEAR );
    Gdx.gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    Gdx.gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL30.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL30.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );   

    Gdx.gl.glGenerateMipmap(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP);
}



public void render(Camera camera){

    //SPECIAL THANKS TO Jos van Egmond 
    camera.view.getRotation( q, true );
    q.conjugate();

    ///////////////////////////////////    
    worldTrans.idt();
    worldTrans.rotate(q);

    shader.begin();     
    shader.setUniformMatrix(u_worldTrans, worldTrans.translate(0, 0, -1));

    quad.render(shader, GL30.GL_TRIANGLES);
    shader.end();
}

public Mesh createQuad(){
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6, VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.  ColorUnpacked(), VertexAttribute.TexCoords(0));
        mesh.setVertices(new float[] 
        {-1f, -1f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
        1f, -1f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1f, 1f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        -1f, 1f, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0});
        mesh.setIndices(new short[] {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0});
        return mesh;
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    shader.dispose();
    quad.dispose();
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) 
        data[i].dispose();
}
```

In my main java class i have

```
   env = new EnvironmentCubemap(Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/back.jpg"), Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/front.jpg"),
                    Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/top.jpg"), Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/bottom.jpg"),
                    Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/left.jpg"), Gdx.files.internal("assets/skybox/right.jpg"));
```

and in my render method

```
modelBatch.begin(cam);
        modelBatch.flush();
        modelBatch.render(instance);
        env.render(modelBatch.getCamera());
        modelBatch.end();

        // Stage
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a cubemap for something like a skybox, that's only over complicating and wont gain you anything. Just create a box in your modelling application (or use `ModelBuilder` by creating 6 rectangles if you prefer, which you shouldn't) and map the texture on it. Just like you would for any other model you use. Don't forget that you want to look at it from the inside so depending on your modelling application you might need to flip normals or vertex winding. Make sure that it is big enough (you could use a different camera for it if needed). If you are moving the camera a lot then you probably want the box to be following the camera so you can't reach the end of the sky. Finally, make sure to render it without specifying an environment, so it won't be affected by any lighting and such.

Of course, whether you'd use a cubemap or not, using a box for the sky does have its limitations. Therefor, personally I'd recommend a skysphere or skydome instead. This tutorial might help as well: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-a-scene-with-libgdx/.

Comment: Thanks for the help . I tried creating a big enough cube following what was done in this question but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452192/libgdx-mapping-individual-textures-to-each-face-of-a-box-using-modelbuilder-cr . When i tried to replace tr[0] with gdx. files.internal it failed . Do you have any tutorials were this was done. I`m a newbie and really struggling .

Comment: If you're new then don't use ModelBuilder. Just use a modelling application like you do for every other model.