# Libgdx Making a 2d image into 3d box

Tags: java, image, 3d, libgdx, 2d

So, I just started getting into the 3d part of libgdx and made my first program of a 3 dimensional box that you can rotate. I.made the box using pure code and no texture assets. Now I'm wondering if there is any way to take a particular image and turn it into a cube by using this same texture for all 6 faces of the cube without having to use a separate software to make the 3d texture

Comment: Also I was not able to add code to this question because I have no idea how I would go about making this possible

Answer (score 0):

The 3D box you generated using code is called a mesh, all meshes can be textured,colored etc.. I think libgdx allows using external image textures on generated meshes you can check this link it explains exactly how to do that and many more

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Mesh,-color-&-texture

And a person answered this exact type of question already

[LibGDX - Mapping Individual Textures to each face of a box using Modelbuilder.createBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452192/libgdx-mapping-individual-textures-to-each-face-of-a-box-using-modelbuilder-cr)